# Get process owner via SNMP

Tags: snmp, taskmanager

In the context of system monitoring, I need to determine which user is running a certain process on a remote machine.
As the host may be running Linux, Windows or Solaris it was decided to achieve this through SNMP queries.
The information I have so far is:

- The process IDs can be queried from the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.1,
- the corresponding process names from the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2.

Is it possible to use this information to determine which user is running a process with some given ID?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No, there is no such column in HOST-RESOURCES mib.

Comment: I figured out as much, also an "snmpwalk <host> . | grep <PID>" did not yield any entry with a user name. I thought, there might be some possibility i some other MIB...

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a MIB that supports the required functionality, I came across NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.
This MIB allows to extend SNMP to execute scripts.
Following [this guide](https://support.cumulusnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/204507848-Extending-Net-SNMP), allowed me to retrieve process owners by process name resp. PID for Linux OS.

However, for Windows I have not yet found a solution.